# Deduce value type for missing template specializations recursively

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I now have a template which deduces a concrete type from the number of bits to store given as parameter:

```
template<unsigned char BITS>
struct Register {
    using type = unsigned long;
};

template<>
struct Register<0> {
    using type = void;
};

template<>
struct Register<8> {
    using type = unsigned char;
};

template<>
struct Register<16> {
    using type = unsigned short;
};

template<>
struct Register<32> {
    using type = unsigned long;
};
```

Is it possible to extend this template in a way that for a given number of bits it automatically deduces the type of the next higher specialization?
That means:

- Register<1..8> results in the specialization Register<8>
- Register<9..16> actually uses Register<16> and
- Register<17..32> leads to Register<32>.

I thought about a solution like Register is deducing the type Register. But I'm not sure if this is the right approach of if this can be done.

However for all values >=33 it should deduce type void or Register<0>.

Example:

```
Register<4>::type value;  // Register<8> will be used
Register<33>::type value = 1; // Compile error -> type is void
```

Is this feasible?

Comment: Instead of `long`, `short` etc. I'd use the sized typedefs; `uint8_t`, `uint16_t`, `uint32_t` and `uint64_t`.

Comment: So do I in "real" projects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you need to introduce a base template that defines the recursion:

```
template< int N > struct impl_Int
{
    using type = impl_Int<N+1>::type;
};
```

Next, define specialisations for the fixed sizes:

```
const int impl_CHAR = sizeof(signed char) != sizeof(short)
    ? sizeof(signed char) * CHAR_BIT
    : INT_MIN;
template<> struct Register<impl_CHAR>
{
    using type = char;
};

const int impl_SHORT = sizeof(short) != sizeof(int)
    ? sizeof(short) * CHAR_BIT
    : INT_MIN + 1;
template<> struct Register<impl_SHORT>
{
    using type = short;
};

const int impl_INT = sizeof(int) != sizeof(long)
    ? sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT
    : INT_MIN + 2;
template<> struct Register<impl_INT>
{
    using type = int;
};

const int impl_LONG = sizeof(long) * CHAR_BIT;
template<> struct Register<impl_LONG>
{
   using type = long;
};
```

Finally, define a termination specialisation:

```
template<> struct Register<INT_MAX>
{
    using type = void;
};
```

For a live example, see [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6b321561273bf578).

---

For a production implementation, you'd probably hide those constant values in an `impl` namespace, then write:

```
template <int N>
using Register = impl::Register<N>;
```

Note also that you could simplify this somewhat by using the C++11 [fixed width integers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer) and hard-code their sizes. This would eliminate the need for the constants:

```
#include <climits>
#include <cstdint>

template< int N > struct Register
{
    using type = typename Register<N+1>::type;
};

template<> struct Register<8>
{
    using type = std::int8_t;
};

template<> struct Register<16>
{
    using type = std::int16_t;
};

template<> struct Register<32>
{
    using type = std::int32_t;
};

template<> struct Register<64>
{
    using type = void;
};

int main() {
    using T1 = Register<3>::type;
    using T2 = Register<35>::type;
    T1 v1;
    T2 v2; // This line fails to compile: T2 is void.
}
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b246d71d6716860e)

Comment: I think the terminal value will be closer to `log2(INT_MAX)`, so more like 33 or 65

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz sure, you can set that wherever you like. In this case, it recurses up to the maximum, but if you know for sure that you'll never attempt to instantiate the template with an `N` larger than `log2(INT_MAX)` you can shift the terminal specialisation down somewhat. Of course, if it's left at INT_MAX you might hit the compiler's recursion limit!

Comment: I solved the the limitation like this: template<int N> struct Register
{
    using type = typename Register<N <= 64 ? N+1 : 0>::type;
};
template<> struct Register<0>
{
    using type = void;
};